# how to search using variables in awk

Tags: awk

I've this file test1  as follows

```
NAME1 04-03-2014 
NAME2 04-04-2014
```

Now I'm able to get the o/p that I need when I execute from the command line but not when I use it as a variable. My awk version is 3.1.5

works from the cmd line: awk '$2 = /04-03-2014/' test1 
doesn't work in the bash/ksh script:

```
export m=04 d=03 y=2014
awk -v m="$m" -v d="$d" -v y="$y" '$2 = /m-d-y/' test1 OR
awk -v m="$m" -v d="$d" -v y="$y" '$2 = m-d-y' test1  ### This replaces the 2nd field as -2010
```

I've used variables in awk before in printf statements to calculate numbers but the above example somehow doesn't seem to work for me. However, I tried a workaround i.e echo the awk cmd in a file and then executing the file as a script which gives me the desired o/p however I don't think this is the correct way of doing things and would appreciate if someone could give me a smarter way.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Posting a script that doesn't do whatever it is you want and then asking us how to fix it without telling us what you DO want makes it hard for us to help you. Are you trying to assign some value to $2 or trying to test for $2 being equal to some value or something else? You posted some sample input. That's a good start but now post the output you want given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a guess but I bet you're trying to print every line where `$2` is equal to a specific string constructed from your variables. If so that'd be:

```
awk -v m="$m" -v d="$d" -v y="$y" '$2 == m"-"d"-"y' file
```